# Solving a PDE using FFT ( Cahn Hilliard equation)

Tags: python, fft, pde

I am trying to solve the cahn hilliard equation using fft on python. My code is simple and logical however it is not working, the final mixture is not mixing correctly , I am obtaining a random concentration at the end. Here is my code, any help is greatly appreciated. The equation has two laplacian derivatives. (dc/dt = laplacian( c^3 - c - a^2*laplacian(c)) )

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.animation as ani
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft
C=np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(128,128))
C=np.reshape(C,(len(C),len(C)))
print(C)

w2xx=np.zeros((len(C),len(C)))
w2yy=np.zeros((len(C),len(C)))
f2xx=np.zeros((len(C),len(C)))
f2yy=np.zeros((len(C),len(C)))
E=np.zeros((len(C),len(C)))
Cold=np.zeros((len(C),len(C)))
Cnew=E=np.zeros((len(C),len(C)))
#w2xx=np.reshape(A,(len(C),len(C)))
#w2yy=np.reshape(B,(len(C),len(C)))
#f2xx=np.reshape(D,(len(C),len(C)))
E=np.reshape(E,(len(C),len(C)))
delta_t=10**-8
a=0.01
delta_x=7.814*(10**-3)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, len(C))
y = np.linspace(0, 1,len(C))
x1 =np.arange(0, 127 , 1)
y1= np.linspace(0,1, len(C))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.contourf(X, Y, C, 10, cmap='RdGy')
plt.show()
time= np.arange(0, 0.012/delta_t , 1)
cc1=1
cc2=1
N=128
k1=np.arange(0,(N/2),1)    
k2=np.arange((-N/2)+1,0,1)
k=np.r_[k1,0,k2]
k=np.fft.fftshift(k)
for t in time:
    for i in x1:
        vx_hat=fft(C[i,0:len(C)])
        vy_hat=fft(C[0:len(C),i])
        wx_hat=np.multiply(-(k**2),(vx_hat.real))
        wy_hat=np.multiply(-(k**2),((vy_hat.real)))
        w2xx[i,:]=ifft(wx_hat).real
        w2yy[:,i]=ifft(wy_hat).real
    F=(np.power(C,3))-C-((a**2)*(w2xx+w2yy))
    for i in x1:
        vx_hat=fft(F[i,:])
        vy_hat=fft(F[:,i])
        wx_hat=np.multiply(-(k**2),(vx_hat.real))
        wy_hat=np.multiply(-(k**2),((vy_hat.real)))
        f2xx[i,:]=ifft(wx_hat).real
        f2yy[:,i]=ifft(wy_hat).real
    # if t<0.005:
    #   Cold=C    
    C=C+(((2*10**-6))*(f2xx+f2yy))
    # else:
    #   Cnew = 2*C - Cold + ((delta_t**2)*(f2xx+f2yy))
    #   Cold = C
    #   C = Cnew  
        
plt.contourf(X, Y, C, 10, cmap='RdGy')
plt.show()
```